# React Native: Sidebar is shown but unable to interact with it

Tags: react-native

I am using [React Native Sidebar](https://github.com/jerolimov/react-native-sidebar)

This is the sidebar:

```
<Sidebar
ref={(ref) => this._drawer = ref}
leftSidebar={ this.renderLeftSidebar() }
leftSidebarWidth = {200}
>

</Sidebar>
```

This is how I'm rendering the left sidebar:

```
  renderLeftSidebar = () =>{
    return (
            <View style = {{ position:'absolute', backgroundColor:'#24292e4f', height:Dimensions.get('window').height}}>
                <DrawerContent/>
            </View>

    )
  }
```

And this is the content for that left sidebar:

```
export default DrawerContent = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.animatedBox}>

        <Image
        source={require('../assets/images/header.png')}
        style={{height:200, alignSelf:'center'}}
        />

        <View style = {styles.drawerContentView}>
        <Icon
        name='setting'
        type='antdesign'
        color='#4abce3'
        size ={22}
        iconStyle = {styles.drawerItemIconStyle}
        onPress={() => console.log('hello settings')}
        />
</View>
```

The sidebar opens just fine and renders correctly, but when I try and press anything on the sidebar the press goes through the sidebar and interacts with elements rendered beneath it. Should I be using `zIndex` in my styles or is my approach completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `React-native-vector-icons`, the `ICON` itself has no button properties.

You can use `Icon.Button`

```js
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
...
       <Icon.Button
        name='setting'
        color='#4abce3'
        size ={22}
        iconStyle = {styles.drawerItemIconStyle}
        onPress={() => console.log('hello settings')}
        >
    This is Setting
  </Icon.Button>
```

OR You can use `TouchableOpacity`

```js
import {
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
...
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('hello settings')}>
        <Icon
        name='setting'
        color='#4abce3'
        size ={22}
        iconStyle = {styles.drawerItemIconStyle}
        />
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: @Amberyo If my answer was helpful, would you please check and select the 'V' and arrow?

Comment: Hi, I'm using react native elements Icon component. These Icons have an `onPress` prop. https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/icon.html

Comment: Does it work normally if it is placed somewhere other than the sidebar?